# english.SE doesn't render correctly on iPod

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I used my iPod to visit english.SE today and, differently from the usual, the site is not rendered correctly; the dominant color is gray, and the graphic elements are not present (e.g., the header image is not present).

[image: iPod screenshot]

For who doesn't see the image in this page, the image is visible [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omoLD.png) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile browsers use [a new "slimmed down, minimalistic" CSS theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so/50689#50689) as of today. This is the same for all sites, and does not (yet) include any site-specific colors or images.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, we are starting with some basic designs to test mobile rendering.

The /minimal style is the "hello world" of mobile designs, it is the absolute minimal CSS and images necessary to render the site.

We will be improving this over the next few months.

Comment: I'm not sure you *can* improve on "minimal" for mobile devices, especially smart phones. When I try to access English.SE on my Droid X, I don't really care about the frills, I just want to be able to read the questions and answers and, occasionally, make a reply or a comment. Less is more.

Comment: @robusto well right now it is not suppressing enough. Give us a few weeks to work on it.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.